# Print multiple webforms by clicking one "Print All" Button in .net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-2.0

I am working with asp.net 2.0 project. I have a gridview in one of my forms which contains list of people who are late in payments. Now when I select an item in the grid and hit open it opens a letter to be sent to that person. The user can go and hit print in the letter form and the letter gets printed.

Now the user wants to select multiple items from the list and hit "print All" on the grid page and get all the letters printed silently for all the selected items in the grid.

I have tried to google it but haven't been able to find any good soln. Any good ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks,

--Abbi

Comment: Database?  If you're using a SQL Server backend, it opens up your options (other dbs may as well).

Comment: Yeah, its SQL Server backend. But I am not sure I am following you when you say It opens up your options. What options ?

Comment: Look into Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it on the client, then you probably want to render a multipage PDF on the server, then send that one document to the printer.